# jQuery UI Datepicker beforeShowDay function doesn't get run

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, datepicker

I am using jQuery's datepicker as a calendar and I am trying to highlight a certain date from the calendar with the function 'beforeShowDay' but the function doesn't even get triggered.

*JavaScript*

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            // An array of dates
            var eventDates = [new Date(2016, 9, 7),new Date(2016, 9, 8)];
            console.log(('#calendar'.beforeShowDay));
            console.log(eventDates);
            // datepicker
            $('#calendar').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                    var highlight = eventDates[date];
                    console.log(highlight);
                    if(highlight) {
                        return [true, "calendarHighlight", ''];
                    } else {
                        return [true, '', ''];
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

*CSS*

```
.calendarHighlight {
            background-color: red; !important;
        }
```

*HTML*

```
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Comment: does anything show up in the console?

Comment: Does the datepicker even work actually?  Doesn't it have to be bound to an input field?

Comment: No, it doesn't have to. It is being displayed just as a calendar without a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you're storing the values in an array but trying to access it like an object

Array

```
var eventDates = [new Date(2016, 9, 7),new Date(2016, 9, 8)];
```

This won't work

```
var highlight = eventDates[date];
```

You should also compare the dates using .getTime()

So do

```
var eventDates = [new Date(2016, 9, 7).getTime(),new Date(2016, 9, 8).getTime()];
```

Then check to see if it's in the array using [jQuery.inArray](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

```
var highlight = $.inArray(date.getTime(),eventDates) >= 0;
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/2k27jt1a/)

Comment: Thanks, really helped out.